# MySQL-PHP syntax error when outputting via php (there seems to be none)

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

for some reason this code of mine just wont go through,  im darn right sure that the syntax of this is proper yet it just won't go.  Please help!

```
insert into users(username, name, password, type, accounts_prefix, comments, 0, 1, status) values('testuser', 'Testuser', 'abc2', 'RSLR', 'tes', 'testuseremailcom', 'username_owner', null, 'A')
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0, 1, status) values('testuser', 'Testuser', 'abc2', 'RSLR', 'tes', 'testuserema' at line 1

### EDIT:  the insert function:

```
    function db_insert( $table, $values )
{
    if( count($values) == 0 ) return FALSE;

    $sql = "insert into $table(";
    foreach( $values as $name => $value )
    {
        $sql .= $name.", ";
    }

    $sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql) - 2).") values(";
    foreach( $values as $name => $value )
    {
        if( gettype( $value ) == "string" )
        {
            if( $value == "[null]" )
                $sql .= "null, ";
            else
                $sql .= "'".$value."', ";
        }
        else
            $sql .= $value.", ";
    }
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql) - 2).")";

    echo $sql."|";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo mysql_error()."|";
    return $result;
}
```

### the insert command

```
if( !db_insert("users", array(
        "username" => $_REQUEST["r_username"],
        "name" => $_REQUEST["r_name"],
        "password" => $_REQUEST["r_password"],
        "type" => "RSLR",
        "accounts_prefix" => $_REQUEST["r_prefix"],
        "comments" => $_REQUEST["r_comments"],
        "username_owner", $_REQUEST["r_username_owner"],
        "status" => "A")
    ) )
    {
        echo("NOT OK Failed to add"); }
```

Comment: If you really have columns with the names `0` and `1` then you have to quote them with backticks.

Comment: Are `0` and `1` column names?

Comment: the thing is 0 and 1 aren't column names.  im using a function to create the insert command.  Maybe there is an error in that?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably because 0 and 1 shouldn't be columns names

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks to escape special keywords ('0' and '1' in this case), like this:

```
insert into users(username, name, password, type, accounts_prefix, comments, `0`, `1`, status)
values('testuser', 'Testuser', 'abc2', 'RSLR', 'tes', 'testuseremailcom', 'username_owner', null, 'A')
```

In fact it is a best-practice to always use backticks for column names.